# Adding an entity to a database entity framework generates an exception 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, code-first

I have a database consisting of six tables (Person, address, email, phone, Education, Birth, Pictures). Table persona has relationships jede to many of the (Adress, Email, Phone, Education,) and one-to-one (Birth, Pictures) Table Education is the relationship one to one Adress orez one-to-many (Email, Phone).
The database is created by the entity framework by the code first, and empty is created without porblemu. Adding Entity runs runs without a problem until you does not contain any sort of data, Education, then throws the exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

codes of my classes

```
[Table ("Person")]
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [Column ("Person_ID")]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    [Column ("Name")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength (50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column ("Surname")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength (50)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RovVersion { get; set; }


    public virtual IList<Adress> Adress { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Email> Mail { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Phone> Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Education> Education { get; set; }
    public virtual Birth Birth { get; set; }
    public virtual Pictures Pictures { get; set; }
}
[Table ("Education")]
public class Education
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Education_ID")]
    public int EducationID { get; set; }
    [Column("Name")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string NameOfScool { get; set; }
    [Column("Start")]
    public DateTime StartEducaton { get; set; }
    [Column("End")]
    public DateTime EndEducation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    [Column("Person_ID")]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Adress")]
    [Column("Adress_ID")]
    public int AdresID { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Adress Adress { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Email> Mail { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Phone> Phone { get; set; }
}
[Table("Adress")]
public class Adress
{
    [Key]
    [Column ("Adress_ID")]
    public int AdressID { get; set; }
    [Column ("Adress_1")]
    [MaxLength (50)]
    public string Adress1 { get; set; }
    [Column ("Adress_2")]
    [MaxLength (50)]
    public string Adress2 { get; set; }
    [Column ("Number")]
    [MaxLength (10)]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [Column ("Post")]
    [MaxLength (50)]
    public string Post { get; set; }
    [Column ("Code_Post")]
    [MaxLength (6)]
    public string CodePost { get; set; }
    [Column ("Region")]
    public EnumRegion Region { get; set; }
    [Column ("Country")]
    [MaxLength (50)]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
[Table ("Birth")]
public class Birth
{
    [ForeignKey ("Person")]
    [Column ("Birth_ID")]
    public int BirthID { get; set; }
    [Column("Place_Of_Birth")]
    [MaxLength (50)]
    public string Place { get; set; }
    [Column ("Date_Of_Birth")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
[Table("Phone")]
public class Phone
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Phone_ID")]
    public int PhoneId { get; set; }
    [Column("Phone_Number")]
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Column("Choise_Phone")]
    public EnumChoise Choise { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Education Education { get; set; }
}
[Table ("Email")]  
public class Email
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Adress_ID")]
    public int EmailId { get; set; }
    [Column("Mail")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    [Column("Choise_Mail")]
    public EnumChoise Choise { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Education Education { get; set; }
}
```

Context class

```
public class EFContext :DbContext
{
    public EFContext()
        :base ("name=EntityModel")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<EFContext,
    Migrations.Configuration>());

    }
    public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Adress> Adress { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Email> Mail { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phone { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Birth> Birth { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Education> Education { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pictures> Pictures { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(e => e.RovVersion).IsRowVersion();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

I do not know what is causing this and please help

Comment: What is the inner exception of the `DbUpdateException`?  What does the code you are using to add the entity look like?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you will need to look at the inner exception for more information.

A quick look at your code, at a guess I would say it might be complaining about the lack of a primary key on the "birth" table